# Codeception POST error with Propel

Tags: php, laravel-5, propel, postman, codeception

I have an error where i make a POST request using codeception, and I get an sql exception saying I cant insert. But if I try the same POST request on Postman it works wonderfully. This project is using propel as an ORM. Here is my api.suite.yml file:

`class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - Asserts
        - Laravel5
        - Db
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/
            depends: Laravel5
    config:
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing`

and here is my snippet of code in question:

```
public function crearActividad(ApiTester $I) {
$I->wantTo('Crear un recurso actividad y verificar que lo obtenemos');
$I->amBearerAuthenticated($this->token);
$I->sendPOST($this->url, [
    'CodProceso' => 1,
    'Nombre'     => 'Actividad Nueva Nueva',
]);
$this->logResponse($I);
$this->checkResponseCode($I, HttpCode::CREATED);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(array(
    'estado' => true,
    'codigo' => config('constants.ESTADOS_PROCESOS.OK'),
    'Actividades' => [[
        'CodProceso' => 1,
        'Nombre'     => 'Actividad Nueva Nueva',
     ]],
  ));
}
```

The error im getting is this:

Unable to execute INSERT statement [INSERT INTO app.actividad (cod_actividad, nombre, cod_pr
  oceso) VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2)]

Comment: Could it be related to what your testing environment variables are defined as?

Comment: @ClaytonSmith I think it has to do something with the way Codeception handles post? (I could be totally wrong tho...)  Could it be skipping some middleware or something? Also, what do you mean by enviroment variables?

Comment: what are your test environment variables defined for in .env.testing?  it could be your test database is not configured.

Comment: It is obviously a database error, but your error message tells nothing about the actual failure. Please run codeception with `-vvv` flag and check the stacktrace, maybe it provides more information.